Can someone explain this grammar feature?
I'm reading Ανάβασις by Ξενοφών. I came across this sentence:

ἱκανὸς μὲν γὰρ ὥς τις καὶ ἄλλος φροντίζειν ἦν ὅπως ἔχοι ἡ στρατιὰ αὐτῷ
τὰ ἐπιτήδεια καὶ παρασκευάζειν ταῦτα, ἱκανὸς δὲ καὶ ἐμποιῆσαι τοῖς
παροῦσιν ὡς πειστέον εἴη Κλεάρχῳ.

It's this word "πειστέον" that I don't understand. It is apparently an inflection of the verb πείθω, "I convince; persuade".
Perseus uchicago says 
"πειστέον, one must persuade"
details:
"masculine accusative singular (cp πειστέον) 
✓ neuter nominative singular (cp πειστέον) 
neuter vocative singular (cp πειστέον)
neuter accusative singular (cp πειστέον)"
Perseus Tufts says the same, "one must persuade".
And LSJ says
"A.one must persuade, Pl.R.421c.
II. (Pass.) one must obey, S.OT1516, E.Hipp. 1182, Pl.Ap.19a.
2. one must believe, Id.R.365e, Ph.1.135, Agath.2.25."
Somewhere (not sure where) seemed to describe it as a "verbal noun". But I've been studying for about a year now and to my knowledge I have literally not come across this aspect of the verb once! A "verbal noun" to me suggests possibly an infinitive and/or a participle. But, from the scant clues so far unearthed, this doesn't appear to be either of these.
Incidentally, the translation given in my parallel text is

"Capable to a singular degree of devising how his army was to get
supplies, and of actually getting them, he was also capable of
impressing upon those about him that Clearchus must be obeyed;"

This inflection/verbal noun/feature apparently comes with some sense of force/obligation. Which also hints at something a bit like the Latin gerundive maybe (?).
I tried finding (online) an Ancient Greek grammar book covering this aspect of the verb, to no avail.
Any explanations welcome ... and if you can give me a link to a grammar text covering this, great.

Verbal adjective.

Thanks. Gave me the clue I needed "Verbal adjectives in -τέος express necessity" ... "passive in meaning, and emphasizing the subject... "

To complete, let us quote the passages from Herbert W. Smyth's Greek Grammar (revised by G. M. Messing, 1956) relevant to Cairnarvon's mention above:

471. Verbal Adjectives. - Most of the verbals in -τός and -τέος are formed by adding these suffixes to the verbal stem of the aorist passive (first or second). Thus, φιλητός, -τέος (ἐ-φιλή-θην);
πειστός, -τέος (ἐ-πείσ-θην); τελεστός, τέος (ἐ-τελέσ-θην); σταλτός,
-τέος (ἐστάλ-ην); βλητός, -τέος (ἐ-βλή-θην). On the accent of compound verbals, see 425 c.
473. Verbals in -τέος, -τέᾱ, -τέον express necessity (cp. the Lat, gerundive in -ndus), as δοτέος that must be given,
παιδευτέος educandus.
[425] c. Verbal Adjectives. - The verbal adjective in -τos is
accented on the ultima (λυτός); that in -τεos on the penult
(λυτέος).

